# ¿Cómo puedo mover las imágenes a una nueva carpeta con shutil?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix

Quiero mover imagen de perros y gatos del directorio `train` en dos directorios `train/dogs` y `train/cats` para ser listo a utilisar la funcion ImageFolder de PyTorch. Sin embargo cuando lo hizo sin `/` al end de los nuevos directorios parece que en lugar de mover los archivos a las nuevas carpetas tren/perros por ejemplo mueve la imagen a un archivo tren/perros

```
# we move dogs to train/dogs and cats to train/cats
import re

train_dir = "train"
train_dogs_dir = f'{train_dir}/dogs'
train_cats_dir = f'{train_dir}/cats'

files = os.listdir(train_dir)

for f in files: 
    catSearchObj = re.search("cat", f)
    dogSearchObj = re.search("dog", f)
    if catSearchObj:
        shutil.move(f'{train_dir}/{f}', train_cats_dir)
    elif dogSearchObj:
        shutil.move(f'{train_dir}/{f}', train_dogs_dir)
```

En efecto, despues de eso cuando hizo `! ls train/dogs` me contesta:

```
train/dogs
```

Y con `! cat train/dogs`:

```
����JFIF��C



#%$""!&+7/&)4)!"0A149;>>>%.DIC<H7=>;��C
;("(;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;��w�"��   
���}!1AQa"q2��#B��R��$3br�  
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

Comment: No se nada sobre unix ni pytorch, pero parece que no te está tomando la \ como separador de cada parte del directorio. Estás seguro de que \ es el caracter separador correcto? y no por ejemplo /?

Comment: Además, ten cuidado con usar \ para separar partes de directorios. También se usa para escapar caracteres especiales. Por ejemplo en el path c:\nuca.py el  \n allí te lo tomará como un salto de linea. Para solucionar eso puedes usar el prefijo r de las cadenas (se puede combinar con el prefijo f). r dice "no escapes caracteres"

Comment: Se entiende la idea principal de la pregunta, pero: ¿podrías poner en un comentario ─en tu idioma original─ qué quisiste decir con "mover imagen de pelos y peros"? Lo digo para escribir su traducción aquí y que luego puedas editar tu pregunta. El traductor a veces juega una mala pasada :) (de hecho, se entiende que "tren/perros" es en realidad "train/dogs" solo que tradujo _train_ como _tren_ y no como _entrenar_).

Comment: `cat train/dogs` suena a pelea de perros y gatos

Comment: Te contestaria, pero como no aceptas las respuestas que se te dan ...

Comment: Senora @padaleiana por favor discúlpeme por haberme _"missed in translations"_ en este momento. Fue perros y gatos en un directorio `train` por seguro

Comment: reparada @CandidMoe ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Tres consideraciones

Tener cuidado con la concatenación de rutas, preferiblemente dejárselas a `os.path`.

`os.listdir(train_dir)` trae todo, hasta directorios. Si tratas de mover un subdirectorio dentro del mismo, va a dar un error de escritura, o en algún OS archivos con nombres extraños, así que se debe hacer un filtrarlo.

Si se va a copiar o mover un archivo, el módulo `shutil` requiere el **nombre del archivo** de destino, que puede ser el mismo de origen u otro que queramos.

```
shutil.move('ruta/src/file1.ext', '/ruta/dst') # X mal!
shutil.move('ruta/src/file1.ext', '/ruta/dst/un_nombre.ext') # Bien!
```

Corrigiendo estas cosas, el código quedaría así.
[Nota] En mis pruebas no usé el modulo `re`, lo hice con `substr in string`, pero si quieres puedes re-implementarlo.

```
import os, shutil

train_dir = r'/ruta/del/directorio/origen'
train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')
train_dogs_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'dogs')

files = os.listdir(train_dir)
for f in files:
    src = os.path.join(train_dir, f)
    f_low = f.lower() # para hacer las busquedas en minusculas
    if not os.path.isfile(src): # filtra directorios, symlinks...
        continue
    elif 'cat' in f_low:
        shutil.move(src, os.path.join(train_cats_dir, f))
    elif 'dog' in f_low:
        shutil.move(src, os.path.join(train_dogs_dir, f))
```

Comment: La mejor forma que conozco de saber si una subcadena está en una cadena es con "subcadena" in "cadena"

Comment: Tienes razón @DanteS. Ya lo cambié. El resultando de tener tantos lenguajes en la cabeza xD

Comment: Yo no se lo que se siente, pero seguro que yo también me confundiría xD